# Filter some Apache Conf to extract all ServerName and ServerAlias, then output them one per line

Tags: bash, sed

```
#!/bin/bash
#extractApacheResolutionName

GrepAndFilter="ServerName|ServerAlias"
RemoveBadMatch="s/^\s*($GrepAndFilter)\s+//gI"
RemoveTrailingWhitespaces="s/\s*$//"
RemoveComas="s/,//g"
ReplaceSpacesWithNewLines="s/ +/\s/g"

grep --line-buffered -Ei "$GrepAndFilter" /dev/stdin \
    | sed -E "$RemoveBadMatch; $RemoveTrailingWhitespaces; $RemoveComas; $ReplaceSpacesWithNewLines"
```

The script is to be used mainly to gather all the URLs of a remote Httpd Configuration, and output them one URL per line, such as

```
ssh hostname "cat /etc/httpd/conf.d/*.conf" | extractApacheResolutionName
```

Nb : the actual script contains a sort

```
... | rev | sort -u | rev
```

... but that's [another question I asked on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52153947/how-can-i-sort-urls-in-bash-shell-such-as-hostnames-are-evaluated-before-subdoma), because I would like to extract it to another piece of software.

What can I do to improve my script ?

- from a readability point of view ?
- from a performance point of view ?

Comment: Do you have sample input and expected output?  I've prepared an alternative, but have nothing to test it with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- This doesn't use anything in `/bin/bash` that's not available in `/bin/sh`, so prefer to use the simpler and more portable shell.
- Not all `sed` implementations allow multiple semicolon-separate commands in one argument; if you want to be portable, specify each separately:

  ```
  sed -E -e "$RemoveBadMatch" -e "$RemoveTrailingWhitespaces" ...
  ```
- No need to run a separate `grep` - we can use the pattern as an *address* for the commands in our `sed` script.
- Final command pipeline can be `exec`'ed to save on creating new processes.

I'd just write this as a `sed` program; no need for a shell:

---

```sed
#!/bin/sed -Ef

# remove lines that don't start with ServerName or ServerAlias
/^\s*Server(Name|Alias)\s+/!d

# remove the prefix
s///

# remove commas and trailing whitespace
s/,//g
s/\s+$//

# split words into separate lines
s/ +/\n/g
```

Obviously, not invoking a shell will improve performance.

Comment: I never thought of using sed this way. You broadened my horizon.

Answer (score 2):

What is "bad match" in here?

> ```
> RemoveBadMatch="s/^\s*($GrepAndFilter)\s+//gI"
> ```

My understanding is that this pattern is used to remove the `$GrepAndFilter` prefix from lines, with any surrounding whitespace. I don't see that prefix as "bad match" in any sense of the word. It seems `RemoveFilterPrefix` would be a better fit.

---

Here, instead of `\s*$` as the pattern, I'd use `\s+$`,
to emphasize that the content will be modified only when there are non-zero trailing whitespaces.

> ```
> RemoveTrailingWhitespaces="s/\s*$//"
> ```

---

Here, the pattern doesn't match the name:

> ```
> ReplaceSpacesWithNewLines="s/ +/\s/g"
> ```

I think you meant `\n` as the replacement,
because `\s` doesn't have a special meaning in a replacement string,
so as written,
this command will replace spaces with the letter `s`.

---

`grep` assumes `/dev/stdin` as input by default, no need to specify it explicitly.

---

In many systems, the Apache configuration files often contain `ServerName` and `ServerAlias` on commented out lines.
The posted script won't work with such lines,
and I can easily imagine such lines in production systems too.
I suggest to make the script more robust by excluding commented lines.
This could be as simple as making the first filter more strict:

```
GrepAndFilter="^\s*(ServerName|ServerAlias)\s+"
```